# ASP .NET MVC Forms authorization with Active Directory groups

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm attempting to authenticate using users and groups in ASP.NET MVC against Active Directory.

I have put the following attribute on all my classes (except the account class):

```
[Authorize (Roles="SubcontractDB Users")]
```

This group is found under OU=Area->OU=Groups->OU=Company->CN=SubcontractDB in active directory. I'm assuming I also need to setup a RoleManager in web.config which I've attempted to do as follows:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="ADRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
             attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

My connection string is:

```
    <add name="ADConnectionString" 
         connectionString="LDAP://blah.com:389/DC=blah,DC=wateva,DC=com"/>
```

Obviously I'm doing it wrong as this doesn't work.  All I want to do is allow access to users that are a member of a certain group in AD.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent being asked for credentials when using authorize? I'm using windows auth on an intranet site and need to secure by AD group and not prompt the user for credentials.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So I ended up implementing my own authorize attribute and using that:

```
namespace Application.Filters
{  
   public class AuthorizeADAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
   {
      public string Groups { get; set; }

      protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
      {
         if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
         {
            /* Return true immediately if the authorization is not 
            locked down to any particular AD group */
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Groups))
               return true;

            // Get the AD groups
            var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList<string>();

            // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "server");
            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, 
                                                 IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                 httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            foreach (var group in groups)
               if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group))
                  return true;
         }
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

And then I can simply use the following above controllers or functions

```
Using Application.Filters;
...
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "groupname")]
```

**NB:** You could simply use `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);` however there is a bug in .NET 4.0 that throws a `(0x80005000)` error at `userPrincpal.IsMemberOf(...)`.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/4c9fea6c-1d0a-4733-a8ac-e3b78d10e999) for details.

If you would like to know how to redirect to another page based on failed authorization, check my answer here: [Adding an error message to the view model based on controller attribute in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440208/adding-an-error-message-to-the-view-model-based-on-controller-attribute-in-asp-ne/7591678#7591678)

Comment: I like what you've done here, except for the fact that you're relying on a simple cookie to cache the fact someone has been authorised. What's to stop me adding a authUserGroups cookie manually and bypassing an initial AD check?

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. See my article on MSDN How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx You need to use the AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider class

Comment: @RickAnderson-MSFT - We are specifically talking about using Forms authentication, your example uses Windows authentication. While I'm not advocating to use Forms authentication over Windows authentication for intranet sites, this is simply a way to get Forms authentication to work with AD, as in some cases the application requires the Forms auth UI components like the login page.

Comment: I had an issue in IsMember method. I solved it by :
`code
var adGroup = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                var groupList = adGroup.ToList();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                    if (groupList.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name.Contains(group)) != null)
                        return true;`

Comment: @link664 : i am getting error on base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) , i believe there must be AuthorizeCore class. can you please help me with that class as well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 32):

It's no longer necessary to implement your own attribute for this functionality in ASP.NET MVC 3. The `AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider` works with Active Directory users and groups. To use this with `AuthorizeAttribute` you need to add the following to your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
   <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
          name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
          applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then, on your controllers or action methods, you can refer to Active Directory Groups like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "YOURDOMAIN\\Group1, YOURDOMAIN\\Group2")]
```

Comment: Does this work when using Forms authentication or only when using Windows authentication?

Comment: I believe the answer to my question is no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610377/how-can-i-provide-an-asp-net-forms-authentication-ux-while-using-active-directory/2634718#2634718

Comment: This absolutely does not work, not for AD groups, not for Roles, only for Users (AD users) only `Users = "DOMAIN\\Username"` works. I don't get why `Roles = "DOMAIN\\Group"` does not work at all for me.

Comment: Works fine for me in MVC5, using the `roleManager` mentioned above: `[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\GROUP")]`