# How do I make AuthorizeAttribute work with local Administrators group in ASP.NET MVC 3 intranet application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

In this ASP.NET MVC 3 intranet application (created using MVC 3 *Intranet Application* template), where users are authenticated automatically against AD, I'm trying to restrict access to a controller to users in the local `Administrators` group. In order to achieve this, I've tried to apply `AuthorizeAttribute` like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public class ElmahController : Controller
```

However, even though my AD user (the application reports the expected user has been authenticated) is in the local `Administrators` group, I cannot gain access to the controller when `AuthorizeAttribute` is applied. Only a blank page comes up. What am I doing wrong?

On the other hand, I've verified that specifying my particular user works:

```
[Authorize(Users = @"ad\arve")]
public class ElmahController : Controller
```

In this case, I can retrieve the restricted page successfully.

**EDIT:**
I found that qualifying the group with `BUILTIN` worked:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
```

Is this the definitive way of referring to local groups via `AuthorizeAttribute` though??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow my tutorial [How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28VS.98%29.aspx) You need to use the built-in AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider class , which uses Windows groups as roles

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
```

Will only work if you are an admin on the IIS server. If you deploy your application to a production server for your company, you will need to be made a local admin on the production server.

Comment: Thanks, this corresponds to what I found (having to qualify `Administrators` with "BUILTIN").

Answer (score 0):

You can a custom AD authorization attribute to place above each action or controller.  I have done this before and did something very similar to the link below.  This works if you are using forms authentication and not windows.

[Active Directory Authorization based on Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342271/asp-net-mvc-forms-authorization-with-active-directory-groups)

Comment: The Administrators group is local though, is the problem the same as for AD groups?

Comment: Looking at the newer answer to the question you refer to, it says that you can get away with a `System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider` in web.config, basically. This is already added to my web.config, I'm assuming by the Intranet application template, so I think authentication against AD will already work. Case in point, I was able to authorize against my specific user: `[Authorize(Users = @"ad\arve")]`.

Comment: That is incorrect. See my article on MSDN How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx You need to use the AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider class