# Active directory form authentication and authorization

Tags: authentication, active-directory, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5, form-authentication

I am trying to use active directory authentication for a web app using mvc5 c# form authentication. I have followed this example to make it work.

http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/

However, using this method the AD group authorization doesnt work like this

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Domain\\group_name")]
```

Is there an extension class that I can use to make it work like that ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to accomplish?  I know that you could construct a `FormsAuthenticationTicket` object with `Domain\\group_name` as an argument, but I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP .NET MVC Forms authorization with Active Directory groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342271/asp-net-mvc-forms-authorization-with-active-directory-groups)