# VS2013 Windows Authentication using login form

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I would like my ASP.net MVC5 application to authenticate against my active directory. Using "`Windows Authentication`" when creating my project works fine but I would like to do that same thing using a interface similar to "`Individual user accounts`". That way my users would be able to log out whenever they want and log in again as a different user. All I want is "`Windows Authentication`" but with a `login form` and a `logout option`.

I have tried everything but nothing seems to work, is this so difficult to do?
Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: You probably would have to use Forms authentication, but authenticate the users against active directory behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Integrated Authentication uses Kerberos, so the Webserver (probably IIS) will handle the Authentication for you - your application does not have a chance to intercept this behavior.

But there is a way to do what you want:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! That links explain how to do what I want using Webforms but I am currently using MVC which has it's own authentication mecanism and doesn't seem to work well with webforms. Is that right?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342271/asp-net-mvc-forms-authorization-with-active-directory-groups/4383502#4383502