# Can I use Forms Authentication to authorise against AD groups?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, web-config

I am attempting to authorise users against Active Directory in my ASP .NET MVC3 web application.  Not only do I want force the user to login and authorise that against the users in the directory, but I also want to authorise users against the groups they are in, along the lines of this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\Group")]
```

Every example I'm seeing does it for Windows authentication.  I am using Forms authentication.  The important parts of my Web.config are as follows:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://blahblahblah" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="AD" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" />
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"
    />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I currently get an error that says

> Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user
>   name in the current Windows Identity.

Is it possible to do this using Forms authentication and how should I configure my app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP .NET MVC Forms authorization with Active Directory groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342271/asp-net-mvc-forms-authorization-with-active-directory-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my research, it seems that the answer is no, you can't use Forms authentication with a WindowsTokenRoleProvider. See here:

[How can I provide an ASP.NET Forms Authentication UX while using Active Directory Role and Authentication providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610377/how-can-i-provide-an-asp-net-forms-authentication-ux-while-using-active-directory/2634718#2634718)

Instead I have done what I did in ASP .NET MVC 2 which is to implement my own `AuthorizeAttribute`:

[ASP .NET MVC Forms authorization with Active Directory groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342271/asp-net-mvc-forms-authorization-with-active-directory-groups/4383502#4383502)