# How to authorize users and AD groups for my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community, EF 6, ASP.NET MVC 5, Oracle, and using a database-first approach.

I'm trying to setup my application so that an AD and a list of users are the only ones who can access it. The list of users will not be in this AD group. This is for an internal application. In my web.config file I have the following

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Above each of my controllers I have the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"domain\AD_Group, domain\user1,domain\user2,domain\user3")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

I've tried different ways of handling this with:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"domain\AD_Group" Users = @"domain\user1,domain\user2,domain\user3")]
```

And

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"domain\AD_Group")]
[Authorize(Users = @"domain\user1,domain\user2,domain\user3")]
```

But nothing seems to work. Either everyone loses access or only the AD has access. What am I doing wrong? Should I handle this in the web.config file rather than my current method? What would that look like? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `Domain\\Group`

Comment: i haven't, but isn't that the same as `@"domain\AD_Group"`?

Comment: Create custom Authorize attribute and match/find/define your users/roles in it, it will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: @MichaelKubala Sorry, yes it is the same

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342271/asp-net-mvc-forms-authorization-with-active-directory-groups) might help

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660251/47589) might also be helpful.  When I did something similar to your work, I had to follow option 3 and write a basic role provider.